# Como evitar o uso indevido de uma API REST?

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que é composta de três partes:

- Backend (BD + API), desenvolvido com Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2
- Cliente iOS
- Cliente Android

A maioria das requisições dos clientes para a API deverá ser autenticada por meio de um token que se obtém por meio do protocolo OAuth V2, mas algumas requisições serão abertas, ou seja, não precisarão de autenticação.

O meu receio é que seja descoberto não apenas o *endpoint* da aplicação, mas também os *paths* que não necessitam de autenticação. Quais são as boas práticas para evitar mau uso da minha API?

Uma solução que pensei foi a de criar um usuário específico para as requisições não-autenticadas cujo único *role* é o de `ROLE_API`, mas gostaria de conhecer outras soluções.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua pergunta não refere se a sua API é em RESTful ou SOAP mas como colocou uma TAG "REST" calculo que é então RESTful. No entanto o que passo a referir faz sentido para ambos.

OAUTH é na realidade para autorização, assim que é entregue um TOKEN é suposto aceder dentro da politica definida para a API. Mas está autorizado a utilizar. Portanto requisições só são abertas para quem o seu sistema entregar um TOKEN.

Quanto aos **ENDPOINT's** e tendo em conta que criará uma documentação de utilização para a sua API, esta está exposta e vários são os motivos... mas essencialmente porque se trata de puro protocol HTTP e já agora porque é a base de todo o conceito de uma API.

Ao escrever estas linhas vem à ideia limitações que pode colocar como por exemplo na firewall do seu servidor aceitar requets apenas de um determinado IP. Ou ainda utilizar SSL de forma excluir quem não apresente certificados assinados... o universo de opções é vasto.

A criação de 'usuário/utilizador(no meu idioma)' específico para requisições não autorizadas nada contribuí para a segurança da sua API.

Mais uma vez o descobrir de um **ENDPOINT** é o menor dos seus problemas. Já pensou naquelas requisições que irão aceder a uma base de dados e que por utilização ou por ataques vários podem bloquear o seu serviço... acho que tem mesmo muito em que pensar.

Concluindo, uma `API` é publica e ponto. O `OAuth` é claramente o caminho a tomar para autorizar a sua utilização. Para mim o `OAuth` é delegação pura... sendo a autenticação e acesso a recursos uma outra situação. No ultimo caso o `OAuth` tem solução pelo que aconselho a análise do que no `OAuth` é denominado por `SCOPES` ou permissões que pode ajudar a resolver alguns pontos da sua implementação. Veja também o `openID`, pode ser que sirva para o seu caso.

Comment: Realmente a API é REST. A parte de recursos protegidos eu de fato uso o protocolo OAuth. As chamadas às quais me refiro são as abertas (por exemplo, para criação de usuário), nas quais ainda não possuo um usuário e senha para obter um token de acesso. No final das contas acabei optando por proteger as chamadas abertas com uma autorização básica usando usuário e senha pré-definidos. Acha que é uma boa solução?

Comment: Como disse... autorização já tem...agora falta só a autenticação. Quanto à autorização que utiliza essa depende da implementação desejada. Como está a passar a informação? se for sem ssl tem de ter em conta algumas coisas. Neste momento também me encontro a desenvolver para uma API e no interface em que é possível definir o acesso por OAUTH também defino os recursos a que essa  aplicação pode aceder ou não. concluindo... sim é uma excelente solução. já pensou também como constrói os seus ID's e chaves? também é importante.

Comment: Editei a minha resposta para o lembrar dos SCOPES no OAuth porque na minha resposta inicial me esqueci de referir e que no seu caso fará todo em sentido.