# Impedir acesso indevido na API RESTful

Tags: php, android, laravel, restful

Estou desenvolvendo uma API RESTful com o Laravel PHP que será consumida por um aplicativo Android, a API é consumida somente pelo aplicativo, não há sistema web.

Estou aprendendo RESTful, e durante o aprendizado fiquei com uma dúvida.
Consigo consumir a API, ok, mas pensei... Se eu mesmo acesso o link pelo navegador, consigo ver os dados json:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então como eu faria para impedir que alguém acesse os dados da API pelo navegador, ou construa um sistema distinto para consumir a API?

(como podem ver, a API terá dados que devem ser visualizados somente pelo dono deles)

E como faria para restringir o acesso a algumas partes da aplicação somente para alguns tipos de usuários (sistema de permissões)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma `API` e no que respeita ao seu acesso é publica e isso vem de conceito. Tendo isso em mente restringir acessos pode tomar alguns caminhos dependendo mais uma vez do que abordamos e para isso é importante as seguintes ligações de conceitos:

1. aplicativos - autorização
2. utilizadores - autenticação

Em primeiro lugar a autorização, e para isso tem o `OAUTH` que está claramente voltado para a autorização de aplicativos, este apresenta também um conceito de `SCOPES` que torna possível definir ao que acede especificamente o aplicativo. Um protocolo que hoje eu uso e tem as suas provas dadas. Já é um standard.

Em segundo lugar a autenticação, este é um conceito mais vasto pois teríamos também de falar de identidade e claro isso foge um pouco à pergunta.

Dito isto, um sistema baseado no protocolo `OAUTH` para autorizar aplicações de aceder em conjunto com um sistema de gestão de identidade de utilizadores e suas autenticações dependerá do aplicativo dentro dos tais `SCOPES` que a aplicação herda do serviço.

Melhor ainda será um sistema que não faça depender a autenticação de utilizadores dos aplicativos. Assim o próprio `API` poderá conter uma forma de autenticar utilizadores além dos serviços que dispõe.

Veja este link para adicionar um pouco mais de luz à sua questão:[Como evitar o uso indevido de uma API REST?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45961/como-evitar-o-uso-indevido-de-uma-api-rest?rq=1)

Comment: esse oath parece muito complicado, não tem um meio mais simples sem ser pelo http basico? E com ele daria para controlar acesso por tipos de usuarios?

Comment: Não entendi como se encaixaria as permissões de cada tipo de usuário nisso

Comment: olá @felipe.rce o oauth é sobre http e trata-se de um protocolo. Comece por dar uma vista de olhos em http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/